# Scrape and compile data using JSON API in R: all possible data ID numbers

Tags: r, api

I am trying to compile all the climbing route information from https://www.mountainproject.com/ They provide an API for doing this https://www.mountainproject.com/data, but you need to know the specific route identification number i.e.("https://www.mountainproject.com/data/get-routes?routeIds=IDNUMBER&key=PERSONAL-API-KEY")

There is no list of the ID numbers, but they all seem to fall within 105,000,000 : 118,000,000. There should be around 200,000 total.

I need a way to run through all of the possible route ID numbers, figure out which ones are real routes, download the data, and add it to a dataset (csv)

I wrote a function and loop that will do this and it works for a small number of possible IDs, but for all 13,000,000 possible ID numbers, I calculated that it would take over a month to run.

I have not been able to do this in a vectorized way, but I think that will possibly be the solution.

```
    library(jsonlite)

    #create the function to download the data

    getRouteData<-function(routeID){
      y<-paste0("https://www.mountainproject.com/data/get-routes?routeIds=",routeID,"&key=PERSONAL_API_KEY")
      y<-as.data.frame(fromJSON(y))
#delete some unnecessary columns 
      y[,-(c(9:13,16))]

    }

    #Make an empty data frame

    df <- data.frame(matrix(ncol = 10, nrow = 0))
    colnames(df) <- c("routes.id","routes.name","routes.type",
                      "routes.rating","routes.stars","routes.starVotes",
                      "routes.pitches","routes.location", 
                      "routes.longitude","routes.latitude" )

    #try for just 50 possible IDs

    for(i in 105759900:105759950){

      try(df<-rbind(getRouteData(i),df))

    }

    #that works but is slow
    df
```

That works fine, but is really slow. Any help on a different way to sort out the irrelevant numbers or peed up the process will be much appreciated!

Comment: Can't you use the API's `getRoutesForLatLon` method to narrow it down?

Comment: That's how I got to the bounds of 105,000,000 : 118,000,000, but that method only allows for 200 routes to be downloaded at once.

Comment: I'm guessing if you need to call the API 13 million times, you're better off contacting their site administrator directly to acquire data (from their DB backend, etc). The time consuming part of this is going to be talking to the server and waiting for a response, especially if they're not set-up for high read usage.

Answer (score 0):

Mountain Project supplies a [sitemap.xml](https://www.mountainproject.com/sitemap.xml) which lists a set of files ([sitemap0.xml.gz](https://www.mountainproject.com/sitemap0.xml.gz), [sitemap1.xml.gz](https://www.mountainproject.com/sitemap1.xml.gz), [sitemap2.xml.gz](https://www.mountainproject.com/sitemap2.xml.gz), etc) which contain all of the valid links on their website. You can download these files and iterate over the valid links to extract the route IDs you are looking for. Each route link has the form `https://www.mountainproject.com/route/######/route-name-here`, where `######` is where you will find the route ID.